# Find result used in if statement

Tags: shell-script, find

How can I use the result of a find command in an if statement and compare with true or false?

Something like this:

```
if [ `find . -name test.txt -size 156c`="true" ]; then echo Found; fi
```

This is the whole script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -ne 2 ]
then
    echo Not enough params
fi

if [ `find . -name $1 -size $2c | grep -q .` -eq 0 ]
then
    echo OK
fi
```

Comment: As a side remark, I would recommend quoting any variable names as you are expanding them, e.g. `"$1"`, `"$2"c`; otherwise the script will break if any of its parameters contain white space.

Comment: You give a vague statement of an objective, and a command that you know doesn't work. This would be a better question if you stated your objective clearly. I guess it is something like "I want to use the `find` command to test a single file to see whether it satisfies a `find` test, such as `size` = some specified number."

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps simply piping the output of `find` into `grep` would do the trick:

```
if find . -name test.txt -size 156c | grep -q .; then echo Found; fi
```

The call to `find` will have no output unless a file matching the name and size conditions you set is found, and `grep .` will have exit status 0 ("true") only if its input is non-empty. Option `-q` asks to not print any output, which would be irrelevant here because we only care about the exit status.

---

To clear another possible source of confusion: as @derobert mentioned in a comment, the brackets are not part of the syntax of the `if` construct at all: you will find that there exists a command named `[`, which has the job of evaluating boolean expression, and returning their truth value in the form of an exit code (`[` can also be a shell built-in); it is this command that checks for the presence of a closing bracket:

```
$ [ 3 -gt 2 ] ; echo $?
0

$ [ 3 -lt 2 ] ; echo $?
1

$ [ 3 -lt 2 ; echo $?
bash: [: missing `]'
2
```

In the commands above, 0 means true, 1 means false, and 2 signals an error.

Comment: I tried      if [ `find . -name test.txt -size 156c | grep -q .` -eq 0 ]; then echo Found; fi    but it doesn't work.

Comment: Then try the actual code that I posted. You don't need any brackets.

Comment: It gives me an error on that line: " line 8: [: missing `]' " if i don't use brackets

Comment: Does the line, typed alone work? If so, the error you get comes from some other part of your script.

Comment: Yeah, but why it doesn't work in a bash script file ??  I put that in a .sh file

Comment: Probably some other part of your script, which you haven't shown, has a syntax error of some sort. You're welcome to posting it on some pastebin site if you want help with that (or edit your question if you think this doesn't introduce a new question). At least knowing which line "line 8" is would be useful.

Comment: I've seen your edit. If you replace line 8 with the code I posted in my answer (up to, but not including, the first `;`), then there is no way you will get an error message mentioning `[`, because that line will not contain a bracket.

Comment: Yeah, it works. My confusion was why you didn't use [ ] for if and I thought that it is a must to use [ ]. Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: @ABC it's surprising but `[` is actually (at least conceptually) the name of a command you're running; its the same thing as `test`. The stuff after `[` is actually a bunch of arguments to the `[` command. Even the `]` is an argument to that command. It's not part of the `if` syntax.

Comment: @dhag I suggest adding something along the lines of my comment to ABC in to your answer.

Comment: @derobert: Very good point, which had somehow escaped me. I will amend my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As I stated in my comment, I assume that your question is actually

> How do I use the `find` command to test a single file to see
>   whether it satisfies a `find` test, such as `size` = some specified number?

where the name of the file is specified as a parameter to a script
(and thus is not known to you in advance). 
You’re building up an answer around the command

```
if find . -name "$1" -size "$2"c | grep -q .
then
    echo OK
fi
```

I’ve taken the liberty of inserting the quotes that dhag recommended. 
This is not a bad start, but it has some problems:

1. If the user runs the script with a parameter of `test.txt`, and
   there is a file called `test.txt` *in a subdirectory of the current directory*,
   then `find` will find it and print its pathname,
   and so the `grep` will succeed. 
   But, if your script is trying to do something with a file called `test.txt`
   in the current directory, it will fail, because there is no such file.
   You can fix this by adding `-maxdepth 1`
   to prevent `find` from looking in subdirectories.
2. If the user runs the script with a parameter of `my_subdir/test.txt`,
   then `find` will fail, because the argument to `-name` may not contain slashes.
3. If you have a really mischievous user,
   he might type `"*"` just to cause trouble.

Using `find .` seems a little silly
when you don’t actually want to search a directory tree. 
You know the name of the file; you just want to test its properties. 
Well, if you read between the lines of `find(1)` with one eye closed,
you realize that it never actually says that the *path* argument(s)
have to be directories — it just implies it. 
It turns out that you can say

```
find  filename  [expression]
```

Applied to your question, this becomes

```
find "$1" -size "$2"c
```

As a sanity check, I recommend:

```
if [ -f "$1" ]  &&  find "$1" -size "$2"c | grep -q .
then
    echo OK
fi
```

to avoid getting an error message from `find`
if the specified file does not exist at all
(and to prevent the aforementioned mischievous user
from giving the script the name of a directory).

Comment: I wonder why this answer got downvoted, I see very good points in there (the main one being: perhaps a full-blown `find` is overkill in this case).

Answer (score 0):

In a similar manner to the `grep` solutions offered elsewhere, but perhaps more simply, you can just `read` a single line from `find`. That will ensure `find` quits *(because `read` definitely will)* at the first match, and give you a reliable return value.

```
find . -name test.txt -size 156c | 
read -r na && echo ok || ! echo shite
```

...should work just fine. If `find` prints anything at all it will have a trailing newline, and so `read` will return true for even a single match from `find`, but if `find` prints nothing then `read` will reach `EOF` before reading a `\n`ewline and so it will return an error.

Comment: @don_crissti I thought about that too, but a couple checks indicated it would would go the whole way anyway, where `read` wouldn't. Some other things I tried were `find ... -ok OK \; -prune` but I still can't figure out how `-prune` is actually supposed to work *(last time I tried that lesson was more than a year ago and I remember it as less than pleasant). Also `find ... -exec kill 0 \;` and `find ... -exec sh -c 'kill \$PPID' \;`. Mostly I just didn't care to write them up - `read` isn't special, probably.

Comment: I'm not sure this could be done with `-prune` (if there is a way, it's definitely beyond me). [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1489405) gives some details on how `-prune` works.